# How get the user input with a form box in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to take user input with a form box in HTML
(input type="text")
I then want to use a formula, (userinput)*0.8/2.5 and give them the answer.

Is there a way to do this? I'm new to grabbing stuff from HTML to use in javascript.. Thanks!

Comment: I would first try googling for a tutorial to get started (if you're looking for a search query, how about 'javascript manipulate html input'?). Giving it a shot and then asking with more detail when you get stuck on a more specific thing ("why aren't these lines doing what I expect them to?") will probably lead to more helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

In plain js (replace 'yourInputId'):

```
var content = document.getElementById('yourInputId').value;
```

In jQuery:

```
var $content = $('#yourInputId').val();
```

Then, calculate your answer:

```
var answer = Number(content)*0.8/2.5;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this is probably:

```
<input type="text" id="txt">
<input type="button" onclick="alert(txt.value*0.32);" value="click">
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery

```
var yourVal = $('#your-inputs-id').val();
```

Comment: It might be short, but it is an answer.